# MySQL Select Use in WHERE IN()

Tags: php, mysql, has-many

***Hello to Everyone.***

I have two table, for example;

TABLE Name X

```
________________
| id |    A    | 
|____|_________|
| 1  | 1,2,4,8 |
|____|_________|
```

This Query is working in another TABLE Y,

```
    mysql_query(" Select * from Y where id IN(1,2,4,8) ")
```

But this in not working,

```
    mysql_query(" Select * from Y where id IN(Select A from X where id=1) ")
```

What can I do?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better table design would be:

```
table X:
--------
id int
someid int
```

Values in the table would be:

```
id  someid
--  --------
1   1
2   1
4   1
8   1
```

Your query could then be `mysql_query(" Select * from Y where id IN(Select id from X where someid=1")`.

To answer your question -- You appear to be querying from PHP or something similar.  Using the table structure you have, you could retrieve the value from table X using `mysql_query("Select A from X where id=1")` and store the results in a variable.  You could then execute a second query, `mysql_query(" Select * from Y where id IN(" + yourVar + ") ")`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "Has Many" relationship, so you should have an intermediate join table. The benefit to this structure is on insertions and deletes. In your structure to append or delete from A you'd have you pull the record, change the value and write it back (or write a procedure maybe).

```
    X       
_________
|  id   |
|_______|
|  1    | 
|_______|               

    Y
_________
|  id   |
|_______|
|  1    | 
|_______|   
|  2    | 
|_______|   
|  3    | 
|_______|   

    X_Y
____________________________
|  id   |  x_id  |    y_id |
|_______|________|_________|
|  1    |   1    |    1    |
|_______|________|_________|  
|  2    |   1    |    2    |
|_______|________|_________|
|  3    |   1    |    3    |
|_______|________|_________|


SELECT * FROM Y INNER JOIN X_Y ON Y.id=X_Y.y_id WHERE X_Y.x_id=1

or

SELECT * FROM Y WHERE id IN (SELECT y_id FROM X_Y WHERE x_id=1)
```

Comment: You're welcome. If one of the answers has answered your question you should mark it as correct.